# Two Threads and a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Suppose I have a class

```
class Apple
{
     bool flag =false;
     Apple()
     {
     }
};
```

```
Apple apple=Apple();
```

Then a thread is created.

```
CreateThread(...
```

The instance apple is somehow passed to the thread.

Now int main program later make changes

```
apple.flag = true;
```

The problem is the thread is **not detecting** it.

In thread function,

```
if(apple.flag==true)
printf("Value changed");
```

It will not print anything.

I hope the situation is clear. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Minimal working example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class Apple
{
public:
    bool flag = false;
    Apple()
    {

    }
};
Apple all[1];
DWORD WINAPI myFunc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    Apple t = *((Apple*)lpParameter);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("flag = %d\n", t.flag);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 55;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("flag is %d", all[n].flag);
    DWORD myThreadID;
    HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myFunc, &(all[n]), 0, &myThreadID);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            all[n].flag = true;
            printf("Value of flag set to %d by main\n", all[n].flag);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output

```
flag is 0flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
Value of flag set to 1 by main
flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
flag = 0
```

Comment: *What will I do?* -- Post a [mcve]?

Comment: *I hope the situation is clear* -- What you are posting is not a [mcve].  It is a jigsaw puzzle of code, along with descriptions of other pieces of code..

Comment: With no mutexes or atomics (or other synchronization primitives) shown in your post, all we can do is guess that your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons, ranging from actually having two apples to undefined behaviour somewhere.

Comment: Do you pass the `&apple` to the thread and then use `Apple apple = * ((Apple *) param);` in the thread (according to your code used `.` instead of `->`). This will generate a temporary apple instance instead of the original one. Use `Apple* apple = (Apple*)param;` and `if(apple->flag==true)` instead.

Comment: it seems, like that. i edited the question. I will try your method

Comment: Wow wonderful. it is working. Thanks Drake. You understood the problem quickly.

Comment: It's not working. It exhibits undefined behavior. You cannot proficiently use multithreading before having a firm grip on C++' memory model. If you'd rather cargo-cult this through, make your `bool` a `std::atomic<bool>`.